# SELECT Employees with the top three salaries for the last two years

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are tables `Employees`

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name  nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    depID int NOT NULL,
    salary money NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (depID) REFERENCES Departments(id)
);
```

and `Payments`

```
CREATE TABLE Payments
(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    userID int NOT NULL,
    createdDate date DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    sum money NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Employees(id)
);
```

I need to get names of Employees with the top three salaries for the last two years.
I tried to use the query below, but it doesn't work and I got an error.

```
SELECT TOP 3 name
FROM Employees
WHERE id in (SELECT id, SUM(sum) as SumTotal FROM Payments
             WHERE (createdDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2013-09-01')
             ORDER BY SumTotal);
```

Error message:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

How to make it work?

Comment: Please, share the error message with us.

Comment: I added error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are way over-complicating things. I'm pretty sure this will get you what you want:

```
SELECT TOP 3 employees.id, Name,
             Sum([sum]) AS [TotalPayments]
FROM Employees
inner join Payments on employees.id = payments.userid
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN  '2013-09-01' and '2015-09-01'
Group By employees.id, Name
Order BY TotalPayments DESC
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71773e) to test it

If you want just the names column, you could wrap that query with another select:

```
select Name from (
  SELECT TOP 3 employees.id, Name,
    Sum([sum]) AS [TotalPayments]
  FROM Employees
  inner join Payments on employees.id = payments.userid
  WHERE createdDate BETWEEN  '2013-09-01' and '2015-09-01'
  Group By employees.id, Name
  Order BY TotalPayments DESC
) q
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's the first working solution suggested here. One more question: is there any way to get only names, without `TotalPayments`? (but ordered by `TotalPayments`)

Comment: Carefull, if two Employees have the same name then the result will be wrong ;-)

Comment: Using the second query I've got an error `Incorrect syntax near ')'.` How to fix it? And is there any way to add `id` in the first and in the second queries? I've tried to add it in the first query, but I got error `Ambiguous column name 'id'.`

Comment: Check my latest edit to resolve the issue of potential problems caused by duplicate names.  As for the error, what version of sql server are you using?  This should work on 2008 and newer.

Comment: I used Microsoft SQL Server 2008. The first query works perfectly, but the second throws the same error `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake, I missed `q` at the end, the second query works perfectly too.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it using `cte`s.

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71773e/24)

```
with pymt as 
(
SELECT userid, sum(sum) as sumtotal
FROM Payments
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2015-09-01'
group by userid
)
, ename as 
(
select e.name, pymt.sumtotal, row_number() over(order by pymt.sumtotal desc) as rn
from pymt join employees e
on pymt.userid = e.id
)
select name 
from ename 
where rn < = 3;
```

Comment: I haven't got any error, but I've got empty result.

Comment: i modified it slightly. please try this.

Comment: No, the same empty result.

Comment: the `join` condition was wrong. it should be `userid` from the `payments` table. changed it. this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT userID, SUM(sum) as SumTotal INTO #temp
FROM Payments
WHERE (createdDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2013-09-01')
group by userID
ORDER BY SumTotal

SELECT TOP 3 name
FROM Employees e join #temp
on e.id = #temp.userID
```

Comment: I got the same error `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
`

Comment: Now I've got even more errors. The first, `Column 'Payments.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` and the second `Invalid column name 'SumTotal'.`

Comment: It doesn't work too ( `Column 'Payments.userID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do what the error message tell you to do, put the TOP where you have your order by :

```
SELECT name
FROM Employees
WHERE id in (SELECT TOP 3 id, SUM(sum) as SumTotal FROM Payments
             WHERE (createdDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2013-09-01')
             ORDER BY SumTotal)
```

[EDIT]
If we follow error message, this should be ok:

```
SELECT name
FROM Employees
WHERE id in ( Select x.userId From (SELECT TOP 3 userId, SUM([sum]) as SumTotal FROM Payments
             WHERE (createdDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2013-09-01')
             Group By userId
             ORDER BY SumTotal) x);
```

Comment: Using this query I've got even more errors. The first, `Column 'Payments.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` and the second `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

Comment: I edited, I cannot test on my laptop. I hope it will run better.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 3
emp.id as id,
emp.name as name,
sum(pay.sum) as total
from employees emp
join payments pay
    on emp.id = pay.user_id
--where pay.createdDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2013-09-01'
where pay.createdDate BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2015-09-01'
group by emp.id, emp.name
```

This should work

Comment: Using this query I haven't got any error, but I've got empty result.

Comment: Try now I edited the order of the dates in the between clause

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 3 Name,
             Sum(sum) AS sum
FROM Employees
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2013-09-01'
Group By Name
Order BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: I think you forgot a join

Comment: @Kevin regardless he has his data a join isnt hard to add in

Comment: This query doesn't even execute.